# Easier proof for existence of equilibrium distribution of markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo

My goal is to get a firm theoretical foundation for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and the Gibbs sampler, but none of my classes or books I have found have covered this.

I found this paper titled *ON THE CONVERGENCE OF THE MARKOV CHAIN
SIMULATION METHOD* by Athreya, Doss and Sethuraman which proves some things about limiting distributions of Markov chains with general state space, but it seemed pretty technical. Since I don't have a lot of free time to try and work through it, I was thinking maybe there is a more straightforward proof for a chain the context of the Gibbs sampler where the state space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the random variables have a density with respect to some product of Lebesgue measure and counting measure

Is anyone familiar with a more straightforward proof In this context?

Comment: in $R^n$ the chain is defined by a Markov (stochastic) matrix, so linear algebra suffices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix